# Mongodb how to show user login history

Tags: mongodb

If I created 3 mongodb users: user1, user2, user3, as a mongodb admin with root privilege. Is there any way that I can check the login (as well as usage) history of these users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB log files will record information information showing when a database user authenticates; the log messages will look like the following:

```
2017-06-28T11:38:50.866-0700 I ACCESS   [conn75] Successfully authenticated as principal mydbuser on mydb
```

A full usage history of each user would require auditing as JJussi mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes (but..). You need to enable [auditing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/auditing/), what is (sadly) enterprise feature.